# How do you do field boosting in the Elasticsearch PHP client?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch for the first time and have the indexing and basic searching  down, but I am looking todo some complex searching.

With the PHP client how do you do partial searches and field boosting / relevance? Ultimately, I want to search multiple fields for partial matches, exact matches, and boost some of the fields.

Here is what I have so far, but I can't get it working. The Elasticsearch documentation is no good.

```
$show_params = [
    'index' => env('ES_INDEX'),
    'type' => 'show',
    'size' => 6,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'title' => [
                                'query' => '*' . $q . '*',
                                'boost' => 2
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'synopsis' => '*' . $q . '*'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$show_raw_results = $client->search($show_params);
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic `match` query doesn't support wildcards, which is why your queries are not working (the boosting syntax is, however, correct).

You can try using the [`wildcard` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), but it has some limitations (in particular, it is a not_analyzed query, which means your input text needs to be "pre-analyzed"):

```
$show_params = [
    'index' => env('ES_INDEX'),
    'type' => 'show',
    'size' => 6,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'wildcard' => [
                            'title' => [
                                'value' => '*' . $q . '*',
                                'boost' => 2
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'wildcard' => [
                            'synopsis' => '*' . $q . '*'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$show_raw_results = $client->search($show_params);
```

However, this isn't necessarily the best approach.  Wildcards are slower, and will pull back many documents which may frustrate your users (since there are many low-scoring, less-relevant hits).

And most importantly, wildcards are `not_analyzed` queries, meaning the query text won't go through analysis.  If you search for `"quick brown fox"`, the above query will search your index for `"*quick brown fox*"` exactly as if it were a single token, instead of breaking it into multiple tokens (`["quick","brown","fox"]`) and searching with those.

I would highly suggest reading through the section in the Definitive Guide on [Partial Matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html), or just start at the beginning of the [Fulltext Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/full-text-search.html) chapter and work your way through it.  You'll need a good understanding of analysis and tokenization to get decent results with partial/fuzzy matching.